# Failed to compile angular application

Tags: angular

I try to compile my Angular application and I get this:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js Module not found: Error:
  Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/a11y' in '/media/DATOS/CBA/desafio/
  desafio_FED/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5'
```

Please, help me ;)

Comment: Is it a new project? If not, what changes did you make to brake it? Maybe just try `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Your error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/a11y' in '/media/DATOS/CBA/desafio/desafio_FED/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5'

tells me your `@angular/material/esm5` module couldn't resolve it's required dependency of `@angular/cdk/a11y` and it needs this module to do its job.

Maybe you could try installing that specific module and see if that resolves your issue:

```
npm i @angular/cdk --save
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have below dependencies installed in your project, if not:

Clean your npm cache (`npm cache clean --force`) and run

```
    npm install --save @angular/material

    npm install --save @angular/cdk
```